# tsc compilation error, cannot find the modified .ts file for compilation

Tags: typescript, compilation, tsc

There is an issue with real-time compilation using TypeScript on a Mac. The system is Ventura 13.3.1, with an M1 processor.

Node version: 20.3.0
NPM version: 9.6.7
TSC version: 5.1.6

Problem description:
When using the '`tsc`' command for compilation alone, there are no major issues. However, when using the '`tsc -w`' command for compilation, it throws an error stating that it cannot find the latest modified TypeScript file. Refer to the image below:

[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40an1.png)

Troubleshooting attempts:

1.Changed tsconfig.json settings
2.Upgraded tsc version
3.Used sudo command

None of them worked

Comment: Please provide error messages in text form instead of posting a link to an image that shows the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you `tsconfig.json` have this :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist", 
        "rootDir": "./src", 
        "allowJs": true,  
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

if the problem persist, try uninstall and install your ts:

```
npm uninstall --save-dev typescript
npm install --save-dev typescript
```

Comment: mine:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
       "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/service/*": ["src/service/*"],
      "@/pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@/utils/*":["src/utils/*"],
      "@/api/*":["src/api/*"],
      "@/components/*":["src/components/*"],
      "@/router/*":["src/router/*"],
      "@/store/*":["src/store/*"],
      "@/*":["src/*"]
    }
        "rootDir": "./", 
        "allowJs": true,  
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and `tsc`command is global

Comment: make sure you do not have ``"noEmit": true`` in your ``tsconfig.json``

or just uninstall and install your ts

Comment: this happend in the macos, but windows not.

Comment: outDir in your ``tsconfig.json`` is missing, 

here is your tsconfig.json file completed :

Comment: ``
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@/service/*": ["src/service/*"],
      "@/pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
      "@/utils/*":["src/utils/*"],
      "@/api/*":["src/api/*"],
      "@/components/*":["src/components/*"],
      "@/router/*":["src/router/*"],
      "@/store/*":["src/store/*"],
      "@/*":["src/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "allowJs": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
``

Comment: Thank you for your response. I can basically confirm that it is an issue with Mac and my current project. I have no issues when using the same tsconfig.json configuration in another new project.